# Jquerymobile ChangePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an Index.Html and UI/Main.html files. Index html PageInit event  I want to locate the page to main.html. Here is the javascript below.

```js
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
            debugger;
            if (localStorage.getItem("user") != null) {

                $.mobile.changePage("UI/Main.html", {
                    transition: "slideup",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: false
                });

            }
        });
```

This script redirects the page , but when I look into chrome console it gives me 404 error

../Site/UI/UI/Main.html but I want it to redirect ../Site/UI/Main.html

Why it add double UI? Any Ideas

Also in the Index.html `a href` element working good.

```html
<a href="UI/Main.html" id="myhref" data-theme="reset" data-ajax="false" class="mobilizmred" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Sign in</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they are not located at the same place? Just follow the console and remove the lines, which you don't need. Simply try

```
$.mobile.changePage("Main.html", {
   transition: "slideup",
   reverse: false,
   changeHash: false
});
```

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have an Index.html file. In the same location I have an UI Folder. Main.html is in the UI Folder.